# ImageView Animation between fragments

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, imageview

Here is my problem :

- fragmentA contains a square ImageView
- fragmentB contains a fullscreen ImageView
  [image]

I want to animate transition between those two screens.

I tried a few things (activity transitions, transaction animation, ...) and ended up to manually do the animation in fragmentB :

- get coordinates of picture in fragA
- animate properties to reach target

It works quite well but there are minor glitches that I don't see in Google Photo App, for instance how to transform a square shape of an image to a rectangle shape.

Hope you understood me, I'm open to anything (the only constraint is, animation has to be between 2 fragments) :)

Comment: Your question refers to shared element transitions (your ImageView would be what is shared) this site has a good walk through of this http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2015/01/activity-fragment-shared-element-transitions-in-depth-part3a.html

Comment: I had already tried Shared elements transitions but it was not working. Thanks to you, I tried again and found this post : https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/postponing-fragment-transitions/